# how to make UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert button call insertNewObject

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I add a cell to the end of a section when in editing mode and I give it `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert`. how do I set what function that button calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method of UITableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == editStyleRowInd){
        //any actions here
    }
}
```

Where editStyleRowInd index of last row in the table

Comment: I swear that I deleted this question. Thank you, in any case.